# Mysql and a trigger updating a table in another database

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have 4 databases in one server, and each one is for a different city, and the third one have all the data from the other databases (for control purposes). One database is called tijuana and the one wich have all the data is called sistemadeseguimiento. So, i made a trigger on when you insert a row in a table called amc and it works, it create the same row on the other database. The problem it's with the update, i want to update the same table in the other database and i created this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updateAMC AFTER UPDATE ON `tijuana`.amc
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
UPDATE `sistemadeseguimiento`.amc 
SET  Matricula = new.Matricula, Nombre = new.Nombre, Paterno = new.Paterno, Materno =new.Materno, 
Carrera = new.Carrera, Facultad = new.Facultad, Campus = new.Campus,Promedio = new.Promedio,
Destino = new.Destino,Email = new.Email,Area = new.Area,Anfitrion = new.Anfitrion,Cuenta = new.Cuenta 
where id = new.id;
END
```

This trigger it's accepted by the database (MySql) and have no syntax errors, but it's not updating the other database. I tried changing

```
where Id = new.Id;
```

to

```
where Id = old.Id;
```

with no success. I'm thinking that i will have to do the change on the other database with php, but i think it's cleanner with triggers. Any help will be really apretiated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any runtime exceptions on sql or php? If yes, post error stack trace.

Comment: How can a check that? I'm sorry if it's a stupid question, but the thing is that i use php in conjuction with mysql, and i havent receive any error.

Comment: FOUND THE ERROR! Haha. I had an auto_increment id on both tables on both databases, and the id werent the same on both tables, that's why it didn't udpate, but the trigger works. Thanks for the time to ask @Ravinder